# Can a QProcess started when QLineEdit is in focus be terminated when the QLineEdit is out of focus?

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi4

I am creating an app using QtCreator 4.12 and am using a touch screen for input. I want a virtual keyboard to pop up when any QLineEdit is in focus and the keyboard to disappear when the QLineEdit is out of focus. I am using matchbox for the virtual keyboard and am running:

```
keyboard->start("/bin/sh",QStringList()<<"keyboard.sh");
```

where the keyboard.sh file runs the matchbox-keyboard command to get the keyboard on screen.
The keyboard does pop up on screen when QLineEdit is in focus. I am unable to make it go away when it's out of focus.

Comment: Typo: change to `/bin/sh`

Comment: it's /bin/sh itself. It was a typo in the original post. The query is how do I terminate a process which has started in focus in when the control moves to focus out.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested that, but my idea would be to derive from QLineEdit and emit signals like `focusGotten` and `focusLost` (names from the top of my head, feel free to use any you prefer) accordingly (say, from `focus[In|Out]Event`), so they can call `kill` or `terminate` on the subprocess (when connected to those slots).

Answer (score 0):

There's no "focusLost" signal but if you want to know when your widget has lost focus, override and reimplement void [QWidget::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* event)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#focusOutEvent) in your widget.

It will be called whenever your widget has lost focus, at that point you can check if your keyboard is still visible (or if the process is still running) and do wathever you want.

EDIT

Here is an example on how to reimplement focus events:

In your .h file

```
class YourQLineEditClass : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
    .
    .
    .
protected:

    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* e);

    QProcess* keyboardProcess;
};
```

In your .cpp file

```
void YourQLineEditClass::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e)
{
    // Create the keyboard process when line has focus
    keyboardProcess = new QProcess(this);
    keyboardProcess->start("/bin/sh", QStringList() << "keyboard.sh");
}

void YourQLineEditClass::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* e)
{
    // Kill the keyboard process when line has lost focus
    if (keyboardProcess != nullptr && keyboardProcess->isRunning())
    {
        keyboardProcess->terminate(); // or kill()
        keyboardProcess->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I cannot terminate the process because the event is different when it's in focusIn from when it's focusOut. Typically, you process.close() within the same event to terminate it but that won't work here.The workaround I have is the running another bash script on focusOut which kills the program started by the bash of focusIn and it works but it's not smooth.

Comment: I don't understand: why can't you terminate the process? If you have a class member variable `QProcess* keyboard` you can invoke `keyboard->start("/bin/sh",QStringList()<<"keyboard.sh");` on your focusIn event and kill it in your focusOut one.

Comment: The focus in and focus out events are different. How do you refer your keyboard process started in focus in when the control has move out of that function and is now in focus out?